# How to know what someone wrote in an input

Tags: python, variables, input, authentication

So I am making a very simple manual login system and I ran into this problem. I want top find a way where the program will detect if someone has written "Mariano" into the 'username' input and "Test123" into the 'password' input and then it would print "login successful" and if not it would print "try again"

Here is my code:

```
print (50 * '-')
print ("Please log in")
time.sleep(0.5)
username = input("Username:")
password = input("Password:")
print (50 * '-')
time.sleep(0.25)
print ("Verifying username and password...")
time.sleep(2.5)
if username = Mariano and password = Test123 :
  print ("Login succsesful ")
else
  print ("Try again")
```

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: `if username == "Mariano" and password == "Test123":`

Comment: Yeah, I think the double `==` gets everyone now and then. Even after years of writing code, I miss one now and then. The best thing to do keep writing code and familiarize yourself with the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of changes in the if-condition statement.

Firstly, replace **`=`** with **`==`**.

Secondly, replace **`Mariano`** and **`Test123`** with **`"Mariano"`** and **`"Test123"`**.

```
print (50 * '-')
print ("Please log in")
time.sleep(0.5)
username = input("Username:")
password = input("Password:")
print (50 * '-')
time.sleep(0.25)
print ("Verifying username and password...")
time.sleep(2.5)
if username == "Mariano" and password == "Test123" :  
  print ("Login succsesful ")
else
  print ("Try again")
```